# Are questions about what hardware is available on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Would it be on or off topic to ask a question about what hardware options are available? For example, I'd like to replace a pocket-sized, non-phone Android device that I lost, but have had little luck finding such products in the current marketplace.  Would asking what products are currently available that fit that description be appropriate?

Comment: Perhaps, in future, [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) would gladly accept your question.

Comment: @Firelord: Looks like they already do (in beta)! http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

These questions are not considered to be [within our scope](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note the following topics are expressly ***off-topic*** here:
>    ...
>
> - Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it

They were determined to be too problematic because they generally lack lasting value, often attract spam, and often end up being more popularity contests than anything else. Such questions are also sometimes viewed as inherently being "help me Google this", and therefore don't mesh well with the goal of building a knowledge repository outside of providing a link or pointer to elsewhere.

You could consider asking for recommendations in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/25/android-enthusiasts), if you'd like.